# Why explorer.exe want's to access AcroTray.exe when I right click on a file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

I'm using Windows 10.

[image]

I noticed the program `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\acrotray.exe` is constantly running in the background. Its name contains the word *tray*, which kind of signifies it will display in the system tray. But actually it runs completely hidden, no GUI at all. I don't want it to run silently so I denied all permission for `users` and `administrators` for it. After that, it doesn't run in the background. But the problem is, whenever I right click on a file (not acrotray.exe) in the file explorer, this error message pops up.

[image]

I use `procmon` to capture what actually happens and I found it's the `explorer.exe` trying to access `acrotray.exe`.

[image]

I know you can add some entries in registry to add a context menu item, which will be triggered when you right click on a file or folder or the blank area of a folder, so I searched the string **acrotray** in the registry. Below is the result (I wrapped the image so that it can be properly displayed).

[image]

The first entry is for another executable. The second one is the firewall entry I added to block it.

So it seems it's not some registry entries caused the problem. My question is, why the error pops up when I right click on a file? What makes `explorer.exe` to access `acrotray.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably registered in some context menu handler. Get "Autoruns" from "Sysinternals" and search it for acrotray.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, you are right! I just tested it.